# ASP.net Core 2.1 and IdentityServer4 - Client Side and Server Side Cookie Removal

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.1

I am working on an Identity Server implementation that makes use of ASP.net Core 2.1 and IdentityServer4 libraries. In the context of OAuth2 protocol, the identity server is implemented in a way to return an AuthorizationCode as soon as the customer provides his/her login credentials through a server provided web-form. The code is returned by the server to a redirectURI that the customer has provided earlier when he first made the login request (see below shown sample login request).

**1) EXAMPLE SCENARIO**

***Sample Login Request:***

```
http://exampleABC.com:5002/connect/authorize?client_id=XYZ&scope=myscope&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://exampleXYZ.com
```

Once above like request is issued in browser, the browser opens up a client login page where user is asked to type in his customerid and password. Then, an SMS token page is opened where the customer enters the SMS he has received at his cell phone. The customer then enters the SMS in the browser. Finally, the server redirects the customer's browser to the page at the redirectURI where the browser shows the AuthorizationCode (i.e. code) in the address bar as shown in the following:

```
https://exampleXYZ.com/?code=89c0cbe1a2cb27c7cd8025b6cc17f6c7cf9bc0d4583c5a63&scope=myscope
```

Here, the code "89c0cbe1a2cb27c7cd8025b6cc17f6c7cf9bc0d4583c5a63" can be now used to request an AccessToken from the identity server.

**2) PROBLEM STATEMENT**

If I re-issue the above indicated sample login request in the same client browser (e.g. chrome), then the browser redirects the user to the redirectURI immediately without re-asking the client login credentials. This is a problem because I have to open up a fresh login screen every time the login request is made considering that there can be customers who have different login credentials. Therefore, I have provided a logout endpoint in my IdentityServer implementation where I intend to clean out the entire client cache and then sign out the customer as shown in the following code block. Here, I delete the cookies first and then create a new one with same key and past expiration date in order that the cookie is removed from the client browser cache in addition to the server cache. My aim here is to bring the login web form up-front in the browser at all times with no caching in place if a logout request is issued in order that the login form is displayed every time a new comer customer arrives.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
        {

            var vm = await BuildLoggedOutView();

            string url = Url.Action("Logout", new { logoutId = vm.LogoutId });
            try
            {
                if (HttpContext.Request != null && HttpContext.Request.Cookies != null && HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Keys != null && HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Keys.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var key in _accessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Keys)
                    {
                       //!!!! Cookie Removal !!!!!!
                       //Here I delete the cookie first and then recreate it 
                       //with an expiry date having the day before.
                        _accessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete(key);
                        _accessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(
                            key,
                            string.Empty,
                            new CookieOptions()
                            {
                                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
                            });
                    }
                }

                //!!!! Explicit sign out!!!!!!              
                await _accessor.HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
            }
            catch (NotSupportedException ex) // this is for the external providers that don't have signout
            {

            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex) // this is for Windows/Negotiate
            {

            }

            return View("Logged out", vm);
        }
```

**3) QUESTION:**

Although I delete the cookies and override them on server side, the client browser keeps returning into the page at redirect uri where a new authorization code is shown without enforcing the customer to login (which is undesired). So, my question here is what am I missing in the above code block? It looks neither cookie override with old expiry date nor the explicit call to SignoutAsync method does not help to sign out the customer completely. Is there some more explicit strategy you might suggest in order to clean out everything both on client and server side completely once logged out?

Comment: Is there a path set for the login cookie that was administered?

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue with cookies not being deleted properly. In my case it was because I defined a specific path for the authentication cookies. Let's say my path was `/path`, in that case you have to specify the same path within your delete:

```
foreach (var cookie in Request.Cookies.Keys)
{
    Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie, new CookieOptions()
    {
        Path = "/path",
        // I also added these options, just to be sure it matched my existing cookies
        Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now,
        Secure = true,
        SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
        HttpOnly = true
    });
}
```

Also, I do not know if the `.Append()` is necessary. By using `.Delete()` it already sent a set-cookie header in my case.